# Child div background-color does not fit parent div when zooming

Tags: javascript, html, css

Depending on the zoom-level of the browser, the background color of the child div has a strange behavior. Some white spaces appears.

See these examples:

**Zoom 125%:**

[image: Zoom125]

**Zoom 150%:**

[image: Zoom150]

**Zoom 175%:**

[image: Zoom175]

**Zoom 200%:**

[image: Zoom200]

Here is my code:

(JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3L4wfvyg/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.getElementById("HeaderContainer").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        if (e.target.id != "FormContainer") {
            document.getElementById("Container3").classList.toggle("clicked");
            document.getElementById("HeaderContainer").classList.toggle("HeaderContainer3");
        };
    });
});
```

```css
.Container1 {
  background-color: white;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.Container1 h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #142D41;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.Container1 .Container3 {
  padding: 30px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
  min-width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: left;
  height: 100px;      
  overflow: hidden;
}
.Container1 .Container3:hover {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}            

.HeaderContainer3:hover {
  color: white !important;
  background-color: blue;
}

.HeaderContainer2 {
  padding: 30px;
}

.HeaderContainer1 {
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  margin: -31px;
  padding: 32px 30px 25px 30px;
  width: auto;
}

.FormContainer {
  font-size: 20px !important;
}

#Container3 {
  height: 0px;
  transition: height 300ms ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0.1px 0.6px 2px 0px #8c8c8c;
}

#Container3.clicked {
  height: 314px;
}

.Header {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Container1" class="Container1">
  <h3>Title
  </h3>
  <div class="Container2">

    <div id="Container3" class="Container3">
      <div id="HeaderContainer" class="HeaderContainer1 HeaderContainer2 HeaderContainer3">
        <div class="Header">Header</div>
      </div>
      <div id="FormContainer" class="FormContainer">
        <hr />
        <div style="padding: 5px 0px 8px 0px;">
          Form
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="FormElementsContainer" class="FormElementsContainer">
          <div>
            <b>First</b>
            <br />
          </div>
          <div>
            <b>Last</b>
            <br />
          </div>
          <div>
            <b>Third</b>
            <br />
          </div>
          <div>
            <br />
            <button>
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why is this happening and how can I solve the problem?

When i remove the border from Container3 it seems like the problem does not occur anymore, but I do not know if this is because it gets hard to see if the problem is still there due to the white color.

Comment: Is the problem just on JSFiddle output or its with browser output too??

Comment: Which browser are you using and which version?

Comment: @RKazmi It is browser output too.

Comment: @GucciBananaKing99 I have tried on several desktop browsers - Chrome, Firefox and Safari. I can check the versions if it is important, but I have not found any browser that does not reproduce the problem, hence i don't think it's a browser-specific issue.

Comment: I am using Firefox on Ubuntu LTS and I cant see this issue

Comment: See my proposed fix below, along with a demonstration that shows the same problem distilled. I should also mention that you have some styles you probably don't need. I.e. setting a default `border: none` on `.Container1` where a `div` has no default `border`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed border size to 0.0125em. (It's weird but worked!).

```
.Container1 .Container3 {                                           
   border: 0.0125em solid black;                                          
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

There can be a sort of edge effect on zoom brought about by one CSS pixel not being just one screen pixel but 2 or more on high def/modern screens. If the system is trying to map several screen pixels to one CSS one and is asked to do a fraction it can sometimes 'leave behind' a screen pixel. Hence the white on occasion, and the variation at different zoom levels.

In the case in the question maybe doing a simple hack, making the parent element have background blue on hover, would be sufficient?

```
.Container1 .Container3:hover {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: blue;
  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I tried out your suggestion and while it solves the issue, it makes the whole element (after clicking on it) blue, which is not what I want.

Comment: Ah, I thought it was just hover and up to the border of the parent. Which element is it that should not become blue? And is it on click or on hover?

Comment: It is only the initial shown box that should become blue on hover. On click, when the box gets expanded, the whole box should have white background color. Actually, it's just the exact behavior shown in my example-code. :)

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by *A Haworth*'s answer: coloring the parent element instead is indeed less prone to rendering artifacts when dealing with different zoomlevels/screen densities. You could remove the background from the child element, and add a new `:hover` selector for the parent that only activates when it is not in the `.clicked` state.

```
.HeaderContainer3:hover {
  color: white !important;
  /** Background removed here **/
}

/** New block with a :not selector **/
.Container1 .Container3:hover:not(.clicked) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

**Full working code example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.getElementById("HeaderContainer").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        if (e.target.id != "FormContainer") {
            document.getElementById("Container3").classList.toggle("clicked");
            document.getElementById("HeaderContainer").classList.toggle("HeaderContainer3");
        };
    });
});
```

```css
.Container1 {
  background-color: white;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.Container1 h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #142D41;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.Container1 .Container3 {
  padding: 30px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
  min-width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: left;
  height: 100px;      
  overflow: hidden;
}
.Container1 .Container3:hover {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Container1 .Container3:hover:not(.clicked) {
  background-color: blue;
}       

.HeaderContainer3:hover {
  color: white !important;
}

.HeaderContainer2 {
  padding: 30px;
}

.HeaderContainer1 {
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  margin: -31px;
  padding: 32px 30px 25px 30px;
  width: auto;
}

.FormContainer {
  font-size: 20px !important;
}

#Container3 {
  height: 0px;
  transition: height 300ms ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0.1px 0.6px 2px 0px #8c8c8c;
}

#Container3.clicked {
  height: 314px;
}

.Header {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Container1" class="Container1">
  <h3>Title
  </h3>
  <div class="Container2">

    <div id="Container3" class="Container3">
      <div id="HeaderContainer" class="HeaderContainer1 HeaderContainer2 HeaderContainer3">
        <div class="Header">Header</div>
      </div>
      <div id="FormContainer" class="FormContainer">
        <hr />
        <div style="padding: 5px 0px 8px 0px;">
          Form
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="FormElementsContainer" class="FormElementsContainer">
          <div>
            <b>First</b>
            <br />
          </div>
          <div>
            <b>Last</b>
            <br />
          </div>
          <div>
            <b>Third</b>
            <br />
          </div>
          <div>
            <br />
            <button>
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But this makes the whole element blue after second click which is not what I want. See my comments on A Haworth's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fix. It's similar to what someone else suggested, but takes into account the `.clicked` state.

Fix boils down to setting the `background-color` property on the container with `border` and `border-radius` properties instead of on the nested container. It achieves this by replacing `.HeaderContainer3:hover` selector with `.Container3:not(.clicked):hover`.

```css
.Container3:not(.clicked):hover {
  color: white !important;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2eqLb6go/

---

As for *why* this happens, I don't have a technical answer, but it does appear to have something to do with fractional pixel rendering with nested containers when parent has a `border`. Here's a demonstration of the same problem in a simplified form:

https://jsfiddle.net/0vje6k5w/

It seems like a rendering issue due to a rounding error with `border`. It appears that the clipping area and the border widths are calculated differently resulting in an inconsistent gap of transparent pixels which can be rounded to either `0` or `1`. The `background` of the container with the `border` property is respected (hence the above-described fix), but anything nested inside of it will be clipped, and there doesn't appear to be any way to stop that from happening. E.g. the problem persists even if the child elements are absolutely positioned inside of it.

Honestly, I'd call this a buggy implementation of the box-model with regard to page zoom. It's odd that all major browsers in 2021 suffer from the same behavior.

Comment: Just noticed that @soimon had the same suggestion as I did to use `.Container3:not(.clicked):hover` and beat me to it by about a day :P

Comment: Thank you. But this makes the whole element blue after second click which is not what I want. See my comments on A Haworth's answer.